# JScript runtime error on different machine for same code

Tags: javascript, error

I am using 3 Update panels in my code.

After changing of my Virtual Machine I am getting below mentioned JavaScript  error in a pop Up:

[image]

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this error by this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager _scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    _scriptMan.AsyncPostBackTimeout = 36000;
    ...
}
```